# Retrieve more than 250 fields from two tables in MS-Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6, ado, recordset

We have two tables which have more than 250 fields. We need to read and update  data using one Recordset (ADO) at once and not working with tables separately (in vb 6) but seems that Ms_access has limitation on number of fields (250).

Any suggestion ?
Thank you.

Comment: Migrate the tables to microsoft sql server, link them into your ms access file and execute then. If that's not possible, enjoy your microsoft limitations...

Comment: What kind of data is it?  I rarely see anything with that many fields!

Comment: Forgive the question, but is the database design normalised? E.g see this tutorial from Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Access limit for [Number of fields in a table = 255](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-specifications-HA010030739.aspx).  That limit also applies to queries.  And the same limit is "inherited" by recordsets based on those tables or queries.

You will have to refactor somehow: redesign the tables; split your recordset processing into batches which handle <= 255 fields.

Comment: The problem is that i need to have for example 300 fields at once, is that possible ?

Comment: Not in one recordset.